# SVM MATLAB Implementation

Tags: matlab, svm

I have a homework to classify multi-class images with Support Vector Machines. I am not allowed to use any toolbox, I have to write SVM code by my self. I have to implement it in MATLAB. Since I am not familiar with MATLAB, I have some troubles about implementing.

Can you suggest me any pseudocode or paper that explains the svm implementation basically? I mean I know the theory of SVM but I am just not good at programming. Or any SVM code might be very helpful!

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: There are a handful of libraries for SVM out there.  Try coding it first, and then see what you can find out with Google.

Comment: This is certainly a tough assignment if you aren't good at programming. Do you have to code your own quadratic programming optimization as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like using LibSVM library. On its web pages you can find some useful hints and descriptions of the SVM. There is also beginner's guide to SVM classification. The source code itself should be available as well.

http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/